How do I correctly set up CRUD in Backpack for fields that use an accessor trait?
I'm using Laravel v10 with Backpack v6.7 and setting up CRUD operations for a Camera entity (this holds a catalogue of camera products and their specifications).
Everything's working great, except I noticed in the Edit form, certain fields where I have modified in the value in my CameraAccessorTrait are not displayed.
These fields for example, where I use ucfirst() or append units such as '%' or 'mm' to numerical values for display on my website are empty in my backpack edit form where the value is not empty.
trait CameraSpecAccessorTrait {


    public function getFilmAdvanceAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
    
    public function getLensConfigurationAttribute($value){
        return ucfirst($value);
    }

    public function getFilterDiameterAttribute($value){
        if ($value) {
            return $value.'mm';
        }
    }

    public function getFrameCoverageAttribute($value){
        if ($value) {
            return $value.'%';
        }
    }
    

How can I circumvent this problem where Backpack is not recognising enum values that have been modified or where I have appended 'grams' to a numerical weight value, for example? Is there a different way I should be using accessor traits?

Let's say I have a name field, and I want ucfirst() on it. I just tested it is working perfectly with the name text field. CRUD edit form shows the value.
public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }

But if it is an Enum field, how can it pre-select the value if it is modified on the fly and differs from the available enum options?
What I can suggest is that you create accessors with different names for your front-end website. So they don't conflict.
